# How to include and use node modules in your Ionic / AngularJs app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app and I'd like to include the node module [angular-base64](https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64) to use in my controllers, or even wrap inside an angular service etc. I've gone ahead and ran

```
npm install angular-base64
```

Which went ahead and installed the folder containing `angular-base64.min.js` file inside `/myIonicApp/node_modules/`. So the full path to the file is `/myIonicApp/node_modules/angular-base64/angular-base64.min.js` .

However when I try and make use of the module in one of my controllers like this:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$base64',
  function($scope, $base64) {

    //$base64... 

  }
]);
```

It has no idea what I'm talking about. Do I have to do something else to get this to work? Perhaps something in my `app.js`?

Comment: I have a feeling the answer to this has something to do with browserify...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The accepted answer is no longer accurate for **Ionic V2** and the `.bowerrc` was removed from default installation.

[Here is how you do it now](https://ionicframework.com/docs/resources/third-party-libs/), from the official Ionic V2 docs.

> #### To add a third party library to an app, run the following command:
>
> npm install  --save

eg: Using the imported function

> // named export pattern
>
> import { myFunction } from 'theLibraryName';
>
> ...
>
> // use the imported functionality
>
> myFunction();

Answer (score 28):

The accepted answer is not correct. In order to add client-side modules to your Ionic/AngularJS app, you should use Bower and not NPM. NPM should only be used to install modules that are part of the development/build/deployment processes. Anything you want to come across to your users as part of the client-side package should be managed by Bower.

If you look in the `.bowerrc` file, you'll see the following:

```
{
  "directory": "www/lib"
}
```

This configuration sets the `www/lib` directory as the home for everything installed by bower. If you use the following command, the package will be installed in the correct location:

`bower install --save angular-base64`

(The `--save` flag saves the dependency in your `bower.json` file.)

You may now add the script tag to your `index.html` file: `<script src="lib/angular-base64/angular-base64.min.js"></script>`

You will also need to inject the module into your app as described above. In `app.js` add the module like so: `angular.module('starter', ['base64'])`

When using tools like Bower or NPM, I find that having to make manual modifications to an installation is often the first sign that I've done it wrong!

Comment: There's usually many files in npm packages. Putting all of this in www/lib will make the final build heavy for no reason. I personnaly prefer creating a symlink www/lib/what/ever.js -> ../../node_modules/what/ever.js
Wish to have an unified clean dependency management in ionic...

Answer (score 9):

- Place the directory `angular-base64/angular-base64.min.js` in `www/lib`.
- Include the JS file in `index.html` (for example: `<script src="lib/angular-base64/angular-base64.min.js"></script>`.
- Inject the module in `app.js`: `angular.module('starter', ['base64'])`.

Afterwards you should be able to use `base64` everywhere in your app.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Also, I've been reading and I'm seeing 'Browserify' all over the place.. Is this another route I could take as well?

Comment: @DeanGrobler No idea, never heard of `Browserify` :)

Comment: It works. But I wish it didn't require a manual copy of the imported module to the www/lib directory, because it won't be automatically updated. Is it possible to specify the direct path "node_modules/angular-base64/angular-base64.min.js"?

Comment: @Vidul Hi Vidul, your solution works. I am new to Ionic and AngularJS, could you explain why we have to manually copy the module to www/lib directory? Why it cannot refer the module from the node_modules/ directory? Thanks!

Comment: @nigong You are welcome. It is like this because of the Ionic convention about [the application structure](https://thinkster.io/ionic-app-structure) where `lib` means _Any external libraries will be placed in here_. The "node_modules" are just helpers and not part of the hybrid application.

Comment: This solution is not correct. NPM should not be used to install client-side packages, only for dev/build dependencies. See my full answer below.