# Using an NPM module from Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

I am using ionic 1.3.1 and I want to use the npm phone module [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phone) to validate phone numbers on the client side.

In looking around on how to use the npm module, I followed instructions in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243203/how-to-include-and-use-node-modules-in-your-ionic-angularjs-app) (last answer at the bottom) and copied the phone directory from npm_modules to www/lib. I then included the lib/phone/lib/index.js file in my index.html.

When I bring up the page with `ionic serve` I get the error "module not found".

I see solutions for using npm in Ionic v2 but am not ready to move to v2 yet. I also see some answers pointing towards using Browserify but I am trying to avoid having to use new tools if I don't need to - feels like there must be a simple way to use an npm module inside ionic.

Thanks for any pointers to help resolve.

Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't figure this out I just created an Angular service from the code in the index.js file for the npm phone module.