# Require node module in angular2 component

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, electron, require

I can not figure out how to require node modules in my angular2 components - especially in my case on how to open a new electron window within an angular2 component.

My component.html has something like this

```
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="buttonLoginClick()">Login</button>
```

And within the component.ts I use the following

```
export class LoginComponent  {
  constructor() {}

  buttonLoginClick(): void {
    alert("just a test");

    const remote = require('electron').remote;
    const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;

    var win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
    win.loadURL('./test.html');
  }
}
```

The error at compiling is saying

> Cannot find name 'require'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include and use node modules in your Ionic / AngularJs app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243203/how-to-include-and-use-node-modules-in-your-ionic-angularjs-app)

Comment: I think you can use import instead of require have you tried ?

Comment: Tried that. No compilation error, but at runtime I get the error "fs.existsSync is not a function" and in the stacktrace it is referencing __webpack_require__. instead of the normal node require.

The new error is described here https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300 but the solution to use window.require does not work for me, since using import instead of require now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know the question's been asked over two months ago. But, since this is ranking quite high on Google for some keywords. I'll explain how I got it working...

### Option 1

In your `index.htm` file add the following block inside the `head` element

```
<script>
    var electron = require('electron');
</script>
```

Then you can declar the electron variable inside any Typescript file, for example, a component...

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

declare var electron: any;

@Component({
    ...
})
export class FooComponent {
    bar() {
        var win = new electron.remote.BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
        win.loadURL('https://google.com.au');
    }
}
```

when you called that function, it'll open an electron window pointing to google

### Option 2

This option should be a bit cleaner. If you have a `src\typings.d.ts` file. Then you can simply tell the typescript compiler to register the `require` global function...

```
declare var require: any;
```

And then you can use the `require` function as you'd normally do

Comment: Do you know if there are any disadvantages to Option 2?  Seems highly suspect that it's not already available, unless there was some reason...