# Angular + exteranl Js is not working. TypeError: KTLayoutBrand.init is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, metronic

I have an angular project and I am using an external JS file for some functionality. While adding external js to angular project, it is throwing runtime error of TypeError: KTLayoutBrand.init is not a function.
Here attaching code.

```html
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
   

const { KTUtil } = require('../../../assets/js/util.d');
const KTLayoutAsideToggle = require( '../../../assets/js/aside-toggle');
const KTLayoutStickyCard = require( '../../../assets/js/sticky-card');
const KTLayoutStretchedCard = require( '../../../assets/js/stretched-card');
const KTLayoutBrand = require( '../../../assets/js/brand');
const KTLayoutAside = require( '../../../assets/js/aside');
const KTLayoutAsideMenu = require( '../../../assets/js/aside-menu');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-scripts-init',
  templateUrl: './scripts-init.component.html',
})
export class ScriptsInitComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  asideSelfMinimizeToggle = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    KTUtil.ready(() => {
      // Init Brand Panel For Logo
      KTLayoutBrand.init('kt_brand');
      // Init Aside
      KTLayoutAside.init('kt_aside');
      // Init Aside Menu
      KTLayoutAsideMenu.init('kt_aside_menu');

      if (this.asideSelfMinimizeToggle) {
        // Init Aside Menu Toggle
        KTLayoutAsideToggle.init('kt_aside_toggle');
      }

      // Init Sticky Card
      KTLayoutStickyCard.init('kt_page_sticky_card');
      // Init Stretched Card
      KTLayoutStretchedCard.init('kt_page_stretched_card');
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the code of KtLayOutBrand

```
/* eslint-disable */
"use strict";

import { KTUtil } from "./util.d.js";

console.log("123123123")

var KTLayoutBrand = function() {
    // Private properties
    var _element;

    // Private functions
    var _getHeight = function() {
        var height = 0;

        if (_element) {
            height = KTUtil.actualHeight(_element);
        }

        return height;
    }

    // Public methods
    return {
        init: function(id) {
            console.log("Here");
            _element = KTUtil.getById(id);

            if (!_element) {
                return;
            }
        },

        getElement: function() {
            return _element;
        },

        getHeight: function() {
            return _getHeight();
        }
    };
}();

// Webpack support
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    // module.exports = KTLayoutBrand;
}

export default KTLayoutBrand;
```

Also, I have added this js file to angular.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di8jx.png)

However, I am getting the following error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJNwH.png)

Comment: Try changing your import statement to this `const { KTLayoutBrand } = require( '../../../assets/js/brand');`

Comment: Can this answer help you ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44647897/5677252